# How to set MVC Razor View TextBox Default Value

Tags: vb.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to set the default value of a textbox in razor view when the model value is null/empty. This is how I have set the default value, but it is currently overriding the value of the model even if it exists:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.PostAction, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.PostAction, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With { .Value = "Active", .class = "form-control"}})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.PostAction, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like the default value to be an optional value to be set only when the model value is null

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out:

```
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.PostAction) Then
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.PostAction, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.Value = "Active", .class = "form-control"}})
        Else
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.PostAction, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control"}})
        End If
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.PostAction, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
    </div>
```